# Can't open pc webcam using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm Trying to open my webcam using `cv2.VideoCapture()` function but I get the following error:

```
[ERROR:0@0.056] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:156 cv::obsensor::getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\program\Python\Image_processing\color_detector.py", line 7, in <module>
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

And this is my code:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    check, frame = cam.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('video', frame)

    
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I searched for the error and the meaning of the error is that the input `frame` I send to my webcam is empty.
What's the problem?